# Each $c \in R^*$ divides each polynomial of $R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We consider that $R$ is a commutative ring with $1_R$.

Each $c \in R^*$(if we see it as a constant polynomial), divides each polynomial of $R[X]$.

($c \in R^*$ means that $c$ is invertible.)

I haven't undersotod it..Could you explain it to me?

Does it mean that if we have a polynomial $p(X) \in R$,then $\frac{p}{c} \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?
If yes, why is it like that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c\in R^*$ then polynomial $f=a_{0}+\cdots+a_{n}X^{n}$ can be written as $cg$ where
$g=c^{-1}a_{0}+\cdots+c^{-1}a_{n}X^{n}$.

Comment: So,we know that $c \mid c \cdot g \Rightarrow c \mid f$ ??

Comment: In general $c\mid f$ (or in words $c$ divides $f$ ) means exactly
that $f=cg$ for some $g$.

Comment: I understand..thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ An invertible element remains invertible in every extension ring (having the same $\,\color{#c00}1)$. Therefore $\,c c' = \color{#c00}1\,$ for $\,c'\in R\,$ yields $\, f = \color{#C00}1\cdot f = (cc')f = c(c'f),\,$ so $\,c\mid f\,$ in $\,R[x].$

Comment: Ok,I understand...thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

If "reversible" mean "invertible," then this is true because invertible elements divide everything. (This is true in any ring with units and doesn't depend on the polynomial ring.)

If $u$ is invertible, then $a=(au^{-1})u$, and this says that $u|a$.

Comment: So, $f=(cc^{-1})f \Rightarrow f=c(c^{-1}f) \Rightarrow c \mid f$? Or don't we conclude it like that??

Comment: @evinda Sure, exactly like that. The notation $x|y$ means exactly that there exists $z$, $xz=y$.

Comment: I understand...thanks a lot!!!